# Add HTML string to head-section of page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So, this is my first post ever here, though I've read quite some in the past. I'm rewriting an old web application. I have a static `index.html`-file that has to remain the index-file. If I could use any server-side procedure to generate the start page, I would, but that is not an option.

However, some of the content in the "head"-section must be generated by a server-side procedure. Therefore, I'm using an `AJAX GET`-request to retrieve that content. So far, all is good; the server returns someting like this:

```
 "<meta http-equiv.../>
<link rel="stylesheet>
<script></script>"
```

The response contains lots of scripts, links and meta-tags, all gathered in a string. I do not have the option using JSON-response as the server does not support this.

Now, if I knew how many the different elements where and what kind (script, meta etc) I could obviously do the following to insert it into the head section:

```
var el = document.createElement('whatever-tag-I-need');
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

This fails since I have a long string, containing all the head tags as well as some comments and browser-specifics (for older versions of IE mainly). I would like to append all the HTML returned by the to the head-tag, but I have not found any way to do it.

So, is there a way? If not, any suggestions on how to split the returned string so that every tag in it can be added seperately? I looked at `DOMparse.parseToString()`, but only managed to get an empty document.